# Pairwise non-isomorphic graphs on n vertices

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Show that there are at least $\frac {2^{n\choose 2}}{n!}$ pairwise non-isomorphic graphs on $n$ vertices

Comment: What does it mean to be pairwise non-isomorphic?

Comment: @paulinho No two of the graphs are isomorphic. This is standard terminology, though since there's no other possible meaning here, "pairwise" is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Explain why there are $2^{\binom{n}2}$ different graphs on $n$ vertices labelled $1$ through $n$. HINT: Think about the possible edges. Now let $G$ be a graph on $n$ unlabelled vertices, and explain why there are $n!$ different ways to label the vertices of $G$ with the numbers $1$ through $n$. Now put these two results together.